# How to group by and count child entities faster?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My query is slow...

I have written following query, this query gives me expected results.

```
dbContext.ParentEntity.GroupBy(x => new { x.Propery1, x.Propery2}, (key, group) => new
            {
                Propery_1= key.Propery1,
                Propery_2= key.Propery2,
                Count = group.Sum(x => x.Level1Childs.SelectMany(x => x.Level2Childs.SelectMany(x => x.Level3Childs).Where(x => x.IssuposedToBeCounted()).Count())
            }).ToList()
```

It makes x.Propery1.count * x.Propery2.count requests to DB... 
How can I rewrite my query to make it faster?

Comment: Normally it should do it in 1 query. if you were doing it with a group by and a select statement `Where(x => x.IssuposedToBeCounted())` this may be causing your query forced to be evaluated at client rather then translating it to a SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

This is called as **N+1 problem**. Try to get all data once from DB, then do whatever you want.
For example in ORM tools, this generally sources from **Lazy Loading**.